# Limiting input to 6 integers

Tags: python, validation

```
serialnumber = int(input("serial number of product :"))
try:
    serialnumber = int(serialnumber)
    if len(serialnumber) == 6 :
        break
    else :
        print("Serial number exceeds maximum numbers")
except ValueError :
    print("Invalid input")
```

hi guys , i have been trying to get validation on this set of codes and i wan to limit the character to 6 integers.
so far i have tried len(serialnumber)=6 but it doesnt work my output is

```
if len(serialnumber) == 6 :
```

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

i would appreciate any help i can get thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to convert the number to string and then check its length:

```
if len(str(serialnumber)) == 6:
```

This way you keep your number intact and still make a clean verification.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace,

```
if len(serialnumber) == 6 :
```

with,

```
if serialnumber > 999999:
```